# How to sort including formatted results after find in cakephp 3 with paginate?

Tags: sorting, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

So I have a project in which I'm working on that you can add a "pool" via registering and logging in, or filling a printed format and the admin adding it manually. On the results I want to be able to sort using the associated username, email and a partner ID.

I have this code:

```
    $this->paginate = [
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'id', 'Users.username', 'Users.email', 'payed', 'Users.partner', 'created'
        ]
    ];

    $pools = $this->Pools->find('all', [
        'contain' => [
            'Users'
        ]
    ])->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $results) {
        return $results->map(function ($row) {
            if($row['user_id'] === -1) {
                $name = $this->Names->find('all', [
                    'conditions' => [
                        'pool_id' => $row['id']
                    ]
                ])->first();
                $row['user']['username'] = $name->name;
                $row['user']['email'] = $name->email;
                $row['user']['partner'] = $name->partner_id;
            }
            return $row;
        });
    });

    $pools = $this->paginate($pools);
```

So what I'm doing in the formatResults() method is: if the user is associated to the -1 user (which is one of the printed formats) find on another table the name, email and partner which it is registered to and change the blank associations to the correct ones so I can display it on the page. The results are working fine and I'm getting the correct text and data that I want.

The thing is that it doesn't sort correctly the modified rows. Is there anyway that I can achieve this?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974456/cackephp-3-formatresults-order-by-field-created-dynamically#30974717 ?

Comment: I get what they say in there, but the question is if I can sort using paginate given that I'm getting it from the database the fields.