# How to sort a Cakephp query using a post calculated field and pass it to the paginate?

Tags: php, cakephp, paginator

Have a formatResults callback function that adds a "custom calculated" field into the entities post returned from a model query in my Cakephp. I would like to sort by this field and use this on a paginate is this possible?

So far i cannot accomplish this because the paginate limits the records fetched and therefore only records less than the paginator limit get sorted and not all the resultset...

Current code:

```
    $owners = $this->Owners->find('all');

    $owners->formatResults(function (\Cake\Collection\CollectionInterface $owners) {

        $owners = $owners->map(function ($entity) {

            $entity->random = rand(0,1);

            return $entity;

        });

        return $owners->sortBy(function ($item){

            return $item->random;

        },SORT_DESC);

    });
```

This works as expected:

```
$owners->toArray();
```

This does not:

```
$owners = $this->paginate($owners);
$owners->toArray();
```

Mainly because its "callback processing" only the first 10 records, i would like to process the whole resultset.

Comment: For pagination to work, you need to have the `sort` clause in the SQL query. This looks like just picking 10 at random, is that the actual use case or just an example? If this is really what you need, and you don't have millions of rows in your database, something like `find('all')->order('rand()')->limit(10)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

After diggin around ive found a similar topic opened by a previous user on the [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974456/cackephp-3-formatresults-order-by-field-created-dynamically#30974717), it seems that is not possible to use pagination sort in other than the fields in the database.

As a result, i would suggest:

1 - Either alter your model logic, to accommodate your requirements by creating virtual fields or alter database schema to include this data.

2 - If the data requires further or live processing and it cannot be added or calculated in the database, perhaps programming a component that will replicate the paginate functionality on a cakephp collection would be a good option.The downside of this approach is that all records will be returned from the database which may present performance issues on large resultsets.